# Difference between conducting PCA on $XX^\top$ vs $X^\top X$?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, svd

PCA: For a given set of centered data $\mathscr D =\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N \subset \mathbb R^d$, i.e. the data has $N$ examples with dimension $d$. Then the principal directions of PCA can be obtained from the columns of eigendecomposition V of $X^\top X = V\Lambda V$ such that $V^\top V = I$. But when number of features is too big, such that $d>N$, conducting eigen decomposition could be time-consuming. Why can we conduct eigen decomposition of $XX^\top$ instead?

It is obvious that $X^\top X$ is a $d\times d $ matrix while $XX^\top$ is a $N\times N$ matrix. Would the calculated eigenvectors be the same for both matrixes? Why?

Comment: How can matrices with different dimensions have the same eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors aren't the same. The eigenvalues are, to some extent.

Consider the singular value decomposition $X=U^TDV$.  $U$ are the left singular vectors, $V$ are the right singular vectors, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of $\min(N,d)$ positive real singular values and a bunch of zeros pasted either on the bottom or the right to make the dimensions match.

This gives $X^TX=V^TD^TDV$ and $XX^T=U^TDD^TU$. The eigenvalues of $X^TX$ are the diagonal elements of $D^TD$ and the eigenvalues of $XX^T$ are the diagonal elements of $DD^T$. The $\min(N,d)$ *non-zero* eigenvalues are the same, and they are padded out by as many zero eigenvalues as needed.

The eigenvectors aren't the same. They can't be. They aren't even the same length. The eigenvectors of $X^TX$ are the left singular vectors of $X$ and the eigenvectors of $XX^T$ are the right singular vectors of $X$. However, the first $k$ eigenvectors of $X^TX$ explain the same proportion of the variance as the  first $k$ eigenvectors of $XX^T$ (because that's an eigenvalue thing), so they are *just as good* for PCA.  The difference matters more if you want to interpret the individual vectors -- eg if $X$ is a genotype matrix then $V$ represent ways that *genetic loci* are interestingly different between people and the $U$ represent ways that *individuals* are interestingly different.

If, as is often the case, you only want the first few principal components and you aren't already given $X^TX$ or $XX^T$, it's even faster to work with $X$ and extract the largest few singular values and corresponding singular vectors, using something like a Lanczos-type algorithm or stochastic SVD.